# Alternative of Equal Tidle operator(=~) when forced to use [ ] and [[ ]] is not supported

Tags: regex, shell, sh

I am aware of a way of checking whether an input is a number with regex and =~ operator, however, a prerequisite is to use [[ ]]. What are the alternatives where [[ ]] is not supported and [ ] must be used which does not have the =~ operator?

I have found that option [ -o ] is being used, but how exactly this would work in this particular case with numbers? Ideally, I would like to get an example of how this line if ! [[ ${NUMBER} =~ ${RE} ]] would be written using [ ] instead of [[ ]].

Here is an example:

```
RE=^[0-9]+$

read -p "Enter the number: " NUMBER



 if ! [[ ${NUMBER} =~ ${RE} ]];then

        echo 'Please enter a single positive number consisting of [0-9] digits' 1>&2

        exit 1

 fi
```

Comment: When working on scripts on this system requirement is not to use [[ ]] and always substitute it to [ ].  I haven't asked why.
I am looking for the most compact way of rewriting this code, since from what I found on google/stack the options with - o when used inside of [ ] are messy and quite long.

Comment: A `[ ]` test expression doesn't have any option to do regular expression matching; you'll almost certainly have to use some other tool for the job, so it's important to know what other tools are available in that environment.

Comment: Are you allowed to put `#!/bin/bash` at the top or must you use `#!/bin/sh`? If the scripts have `#!/bin/bash` then using bash features is fine.

Comment: I ask because there are lots of people who have incorrect ideas about script portability. They think that portable scripts must avoid all bash-isms. That's true if the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, but if it's `#!/bin/bash` then you're already requiring bash; might as well use bash features. In practice bash is super portable. -- "I haven't asked why." Ask why. :)

Comment: You shouldn't be using (e.g.) `[ "$x" -eq 1 -o "$x" -eq 2 ]` in `sh` any more than you should in `bash`. (`-o` is not required by POSIX.) Use `[ "$x" -eq 1 ] || [ "$x" -eq 2 ]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, what's the best way/most compact way of rewriting this: if the number read is not a positive number consisting of [0-9] digits, do something

Comment: The best way is probably to use a language with proper data types, rather than having to implement them yourself via string validation and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting POSIX sh you can use `grep` with `-q` for silent output, `-x` for whole line matches, and `-E` for extended regex syntax.

```
if ! printf '%s\n' "$number" | grep -qxE '[0-9]+'; then
    exit 1
fi
```

If you need even more portability beyond POSIX, stick to basic regex syntax and redirect `grep`'s output to `/dev/null`.

```
if ! printf '%s\n' "$number" | grep '^[0-9]\+$' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Both versions rely on `$number` being a one-line string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the POSIX utility `expr` for regular expression matching:

```
if expr "$number" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' > /dev/null; then
  echo "$number is a number"
fi
```

Note that all matches are anchored to the start of the string, and therefore the '^' anchor is not needed. (If you wanted to disregard some prefix of the string, you would need to add `.*` to the beginning of the regular expression explicitly.)

`expr` outputs either the number of matched characters or the value of the first capture group. It also only supports POSIX BREs (Basic Regular Expressions).

For more information, see -
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_13_01

Comment: `[0-9]\{1,\}` works too (not that it's any shorter in this case)

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot about brace expressions. For some reason, it always surprises me that they are part of POSIX, but not `+`. (I guess because `+` really is just a special case. `*` is, too, but at least it's one of the fundamental regular expression operators. Brace expressions themselves are just a short-cut to the type of repetition I used in the answer.)

Comment: Yeah this one is the one I was looking for, thanks. One last question, 
if [ expr "${number} : '[0-9][0-9]*$' > /dev/null ]; is literally the same, you just skipped the [ ] right?

Comment: Also, what are the alternatives to for (( i=1; i<${NUMBER}; i++ )) ... in plain shell, where (( )) is not supported?

Comment: Adding the `[` is absolutely incorrect; `[`(aka `test`) is a command, and you want `if` to test the exit status of `expr`, not `[`. (Adding the brackets will trigger a syntax error from `[`, as the following arguments to not form a valid test expression.)

Comment: In place of `((...))`, you would have to use something like `i=1; while [ "$i" -lt "$NUMBER" ]; do ...; i=$((i+1)); done`.